# Deselecting ListView Item if already same item selected WPF

Tags: wpf

I had a ListView collection in WPF.

Let's say items were Apple, Banana, Cherry.

Assume user selected Banana at first.

If again user clicks on Banana the item was still selected.

I want to deselect the item on user click, If the same item was already selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SelectionMode` to `Multiple` or handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListViewItem` containers depending on whether you want to be able to select several items or not:

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    if (lvi.IsSelected)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        lvi.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                         Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <s:String>Apple</s:String>
    <s:String>Banana</s:String>
    <s:String>Cherry</s:String>
</ListView>
```